# maven v3.0.5 cannot find sqoop artifact

Tags: maven, sqoop

i am trying to build my project with maven v3.0.5 and jdk 1.7. snippets of my pom xml looks like the following.

```
<properties>
 <sqoop.version>1.4.4</sqoop.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.sqoop</groupId>
  <artifactId>sqoop</artifactId>
  <version>${sqoop.version}</version>
 </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

when i run "mvn clean package" i see the following error:

```
Could not find artifact org.apache.sqoop:sqoop:jar:1.4.4 in central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
```

usually and typically, i go to mvnrepository.com, and search for artifacts, and whatever artifacts i can find there, i have always been able to simply reference them in my pom.xml. according to this link, http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.sqoop/sqoop/1.4.4, this artifact should exist?

i can't really browse http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2.

```
Browsing for this directory has been disabled.
View this directory's contents on http://search.maven.org instead.
```

so i decided to use the search site for sqoop.

```
http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Csqoop
```

it seems to me that this artifact exists, but somehow, i can't access it. any ideas on what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is this resolved ? I meet the same thing when using sqoop 1.4.5 This is very unreasonable that no artifact for sqoop jar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT -

The Sqoop JAR varies based on what version of Hadoop you're using.

If you want to build against some Hadoop 0.23.x variant, what you need is the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.sqoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqoop</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.4</version>
    <classifier>hadoop23</classifier>
</dependency>
```

You will be able to see what classifiers are available using Eclipse.  Right-click pom.xml, Maven --> Add Dependency.  Type 'sqoop' in the search box, then expand the collapsed menu for org.apache.sqoop and note the options, `hadoop23`, `hadoop100`, etc.

Comment: when i tried that, i no longer get the error "Cannot find artifact...", however, now, i cannot reference any sqoop classes from inside my code. in eclipse, when i look at the "Maven Dependencies" there are no sqoop jars. any idea what's going on?

Comment: You can also use the version 1.4.0-incubating

Comment: yes, using 1.4.0-incubating works, but i want to use 1.4.4, which is part of my problem.

Comment: Its clear from the official release notes of Sqoop that no jar is available for the version 1.4.4 , only in the latest release they provide a bundled tar file. http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/sqoop/1.4.4

Comment: I edited my original answer - please let me know if this works instead.

Comment: @tech-idiot could you enlighten me why if that jar is not available, does it show up as "available" just like any other jars? by available i mean why does it show up on mvnrepository.com like a log4j jar/dependency jar? is this just something quirky with maven and repositories in general?

Comment: Glad to hear it!  Please help me out as being new to SE and vote up the answer =]  Thanks!